# Actionscript: I am trying to use actionscript buttons with a key press instead of a mouse click

Tags: button, actionscript, keypress

This in flash.
I have a bunch of buttons that I want to animate once I've hit the corresponding key for. Each button has an "Up," "Over," "Down," and "Hit" state.

I get the error I keep getting is:

> Access of possibly undefined property enabled through a reference with static type Class.
>   I think there is something wrong with the way I called "Pad7" which is a button with a class name of "Pad7."

Here is my code

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_KeyboardDownHandler);

    function fl_KeyboardDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
            Pad7.enabled = false;
            if (event.keyCode == 81)
            {
                    trace("Q");
                    Pad7.enabled = true;
                    //Pad7.gotoAndPlay();
            }

    }
```

Comment: "I think there is something wrong with the way I called "Pad7" which is a button with a class name of "Pad7". Well, then the first thing to try is probably to not use the same name, same identifier, for both the class and the instance, the button. For example by naming the button "pad7".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a class called Pad7 and then you also have an instance of that class called Pad7. At least make sure that your instance of Pad7 is named something that you can access. You probably meant to do something similar to this:

```
var myPad7Instance:Pad7;
function myInitFunction():void {
    myPad7Instance = new Pad7();
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_KeyboardDownHandler);
}

function fl_KeyboardDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
        myPad7Instance.enabled = false;
        if (event.keyCode == 81)
        {
                trace("Q");
                myPad7Instance.enabled = true;
                //myPad7Instance.gotoAndPlay();
        }

}
```